IntelliJ/Android Studio: can one out-dent a closing XML bracket?
I would like the closing bracket of XML elements to be formatted this way:
<element_with_attributes
   attr1="value1"
   attr2="value2"
   attr3="value3"
/>
...
<element_with_attributes_and_children
   attr1="value1"
   attr2="value2"
   attr3="value3"
   >
   <child_element1>
   <child_element2
       attr1"="value1"
   />
   <child_element3_with_grandchild
       attr1"="value1"
       >
       <grandchild_element>
   </child_element3>
   ...
</element_with_attributes_and_children>

i.e. a closing bracket > should be indented one level if there are any child-elements following the element's attribues (here e.g. for element_with_attributes_and_children and child_element3_with_grandchild) but a closing bracket /> should not be indented but be on the same level as the corresponding opening bracket (here e.g. for element_with_attributes and child_element2). In my opinion this would make it easier to visually spot the closing brackets for each element.
The current settings in IntelliJ and Android Studio always indent the closing brackets, no matter whether it is a > or a />. Can one adjust that somehow? I found no such option in the program's File -> Settings -> Code Style -> XML.
